# Adding multiple items to an array using unshift

Tags: jquery

I'm using unshift to add data to the beginning of an array

```
x.done(function(data) {
    data.unshift({ "data": {
        "number": "default",
        "description": "Account Default"
    } });
});
```

But it's giving me `Uncaught TypeError: data.unshift is not a function`

Although, I have used unshift before, and it works fine. I cannot work out what the issue is with this one.

I was also trying to add a second array inside `data` but this was returning a different error (I think I got the syntax wrong)

```
data.unshift({ "data": {
    "number": "default",
    "description": "Account Default"
},
{
    "number": "default",
    "description": "Account Default"
} });
```

Comment: You are sure that `data` is an `array`?

Comment: below it, I use `for(var i in data) {`to loop through. it's JSON data

Comment: unshift is only functional with array

Comment: It means you are trying to use `unshift` with an `object`?

Comment: Oh, I've just seen it's not returning the same format. It looks like this `01234: {data: {…}, seq: "4", customer: "1234", display: "Number 01234", number: "01234", …}` so `data` is inside another key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var data = [{
    "data": {
        "number": "default",
        "description": "Account Default"
    }
}];


data.unshift({
    "data": {
        "number": "default",
        "description": "new Data 1"
    }
})

data.unshift({
    "data": {
        "number": "default",
        "description": "new Data 2"
    }
});

// 3) [{…}, {…}, {…}] results 3
```

Answer (score 0):

`unshift` works only with `Array`. But to add data at the beginning of an `object`, you can use ES6 `spread` syntax:

```
data = {
         { "data": {
            "number": "default",
            "description": "Account Default"
           } 
         }, 
         ...data
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `unshift` only works with the `Array` type, are you certain that `data` is in fact of type `Array`?
You could for example check this with the `Array.isArray()` method:

```js
x.done(function(data) {
    console.log(Array.isArray(data));
});
```

Regarding your second problem it is indeed just a syntax error.